# How can I use WhenEvent with multiple conditions inside NDSolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, conditional, event-detection

I would like to use WhenEvent but I'm not getting what I want: I set the initial condition var\epsilon=0;
I want var\epsilon to change continuously over time, from to 0.1 if s'[t]>=0 or to -0.1 if s'[t]<0 whenever theta is greater than 2pi. I also need it to change to zero again when H[t] reaches the value Hf I define. Initially, H[t] is constant and equal to H0. When theta>=2pi, H[t] stops being constant. When Hf is reached, H[t] is constant and equal to Hf. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

```
 Hf=-0.4;
   sol = NDSolve[{s''[t] == -(1/s[t]) + 1^2/s[t]^3 + var\[Epsilon][t], 
    var\[Epsilon]'[t] == 0, \[Theta]'[t] == 1/s[t]^2, 
    H'[t] == s'[t] var\[Epsilon][t], s[0] == 1, 
    s'[0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0, var\[Epsilon][0] == 0, 
    H[0] == -(1/2), 
    WhenEvent[s'[t] > 0, 
     If[\[Theta][t] >= 2 \[Pi], var\[Epsilon][t] -> 0.1]], 
    WhenEvent[s'[t] < 0, 
     If[\[Theta][t] >= 2 \[Pi], var\[Epsilon][t] -> -0.1]], 
    WhenEvent[H[t] == Hf, var\[Epsilon][t] -> 0]}, {s, s', \[Theta],
     var\[Epsilon], H},
   {t, 0, 100}, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}];
```

Comment: Your code checks for s'[t]>0, but your question indicated that the check should be for s'[t]>=0; that's a coding error, but I don't believe that it's the source of the problem.  If I understand WhenEvent correctly, it's looking for the event to BECOME true, but your condition (s'[t]>=0) started as true, so WhenEvent is never triggered.  As long as none of the events is triggered, all of your derivates (with the exception of \[Theta]'[t]) remain zero so the system never changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this really solves your problem, but I added a WhenEvent to get things started.

```
Hf = -0.4; 
sol = NDSolve[{Derivative[2][s][t] == -(1/s[t]) + 1^2/s[t]^3 + 
      var\[Epsilon][t], 
         Derivative[1][var\[Epsilon]][t] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] == 1/s[t]^2, 
         Derivative[1][H][t] == Derivative[1][s][t]*var\[Epsilon][t], 
    s[0] == 1, 
         Derivative[1][s][0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0, 
    var\[Epsilon][0] == 0, H[0] == -(1/2), 
         WhenEvent[\[Theta][t] >= 2*Pi, 
     If[Derivative[1][s][t] >= 0, var\[Epsilon][t] -> 0.1]], 
         WhenEvent[Derivative[1][s][t] > 0, 
     If[\[Theta][t] >= 2*Pi, var\[Epsilon][t] -> 0.1]], 
         WhenEvent[Derivative[1][s][t] < 0, 
     If[\[Theta][t] >= 2*Pi, var\[Epsilon][t] -> -0.1]], 
         WhenEvent[H[t] == Hf, var\[Epsilon][t] -> 0]}, {s, 
    Derivative[1][s], \[Theta], var\[Epsilon], H}, 
       {t, 0, 100}, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}];
```

Comment: Apologies for the ugly formatting.  I followed these instructions, but it still looks hideous: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site